# Spring Boot Setup: org.hibernate.HibernateException: No CurrentSessionContext configured

Tags: spring-boot

Hi there i have a small Spring Boot Setup and Problems accessing my database.

This is my Setup starting with Controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/myproject/users")
public class UserController {

private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory
        .getLogger("UserController.class");

private UserService userService;

@Autowired
public UserController(UserService userService) {
    this.userService = userService;
}
....
```

This is my DAO he extends an abstract DAO with all CRUD methods:

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public class UserDaoImpl<T> extends AbstractDAO<User, Integer> implements
    UserDao {

@Autowired
public UserDaoImpl(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
    super(sessionFactory);
}

protected Class<User> getEntityClass() {
    return User.class;
}

public User getUserByMail(String email) {
    User result = null;
    Criteria criteria = getCriteria();
    criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("email", email));
    if (criteria.uniqueResult() != null) {
        result = (User) criteria.uniqueResult();
    }
    return result;
}
protected final Session getCurrentSession() {
    return this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
}

.....
```

And finally the service:

```
@Component
@Transactional
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

private UserDao userDao;

@Autowired
public UserServiceImpl(UserDao userDao) {
    this.userDao = userDao;
}


public List<User> getAllUsers() {
    return this.userDao.findAll();
}
....
```

Here are my application settings:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://10.0.0.15:3306/schema
spring.datasource.username=test
spring.datasource.password=test

# Hibernate
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create

# Tomcat
server.port = 9080
```

And this is my Application.java:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan({"core", "controller"})
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Application
{
   public static void main(String[] args) {
   ....
   }
@Bean
public SessionFactory sessionFactory(HibernateEntityManagerFactory hemf) {
   return hemf.getSessionFactory();
}
....
```

My Problem is now, that the Sessionfactory is correctly constructed, all beans are loaded, but when my DAO tries to access the database i get an Exception:

'org.hibernate.HibernateException: No CurrentSessionContext configured'

I was searching on Stackoverflow very much and found out, that the problem is that Spring is not able to open the CurrentSessionContext. I am able to do this manually, but i want Spring-Boot handling my transactions. Does anyone recognize my mistake in the setup?

I already tried to stick to this solution: [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26667910/no-currentsessioncontext-configured)

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Adding the following to my application settings worked for me:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.current_session_context_class=org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SpringSessionContext
```

Refer to the following: [No CurrentSessionContext configured](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26667910/no-currentsessioncontext-configured)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please consider editing your post to add more explanation about what your code does and why it will solve the problem. An answer that mostly just contains code (even if it's working) usually wont help the OP to understand their problem. If the explanation is in the link please quote the relevant sections in your answer here.